# Non-deprecated PackagingOptions?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

According to the current [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions), it seems to me that all packaging options are deprecated? So, what shall be used?

E.g. currently I use

```
packagingOptions {
    merge 'META-INF/NOTICE.md'
    merge 'META-INF/LICENSE.md'
}
```

but merge is described as [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/dsl/PackagingOptions#merge):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to source code comments:

```
@Deprecated(
    "This property is deprecated. Use resources.merges instead.",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("resources.merges")
)
val merges: MutableSet<String>

@Deprecated(
    "This method is deprecated. Use resources.merges.add() instead.",
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("resources.merges.add(pattern)")
)
fun merge(pattern: String)
```

Thus, it becomes:

```
// In build.gradle.kts
android {
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            merges.add("META-INF/NOTICE.md")
        }
    }
}
```